# JSOUP get element with multiple classes

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

I am trying to read all `<div>`s with the class = `"listitem show-in-category"` from an HTML page. Furthermore, I want to get the `itemprop` fields like `itemprop="description"` and `itemprop="image"` under each . An example of the `<div>` is below:

```
<div class="listitem show-in-category">
    <img itemprop="image" alt="For the Trumpets Shall Sound" class="poster pull-left" src=
    "/images/shows/rectangle-poster/resized/188x282/4423-1390493634-forthetrumpets-rec.jpg"
    title="For the Trumpets Shall Sound">

    <h2 itemprop="name"><a href=
    "http://www.londonboxoffice.co.uk/for-the-trumpets-shall-sound-tickets">
    For the Trumpets Shall Sound</a></h2>

    <p itemprop="description"><p>Ruth is clearing out her Mother's attic, with the help of her son
    Jamie, when they make an interesting discovery.<br>
    <br></p>
</div>
```

On the [JSOUP selector page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax), it is stated that I can access all divs by class name as:

```
Elements mydesiredclass = doc.select("div.class")
```

**1)** However, for the class name above this does not work, probably since the class name has spaces? What syntax should I use to get all divs with the given class name?

**2)** Also, once I manage to get all divs and am looping through them, how can I get their `description` and `img` properties?

Comment: ```description``` is not really a property of anything. Do you mean the ```alt``` and ```title``` tags of ```img```?

Comment: Sorry @luksch, I re-edited. I want to get this part:  `<p itemprop="description"><p>Ruth is clearing out her Mother's attic...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces in the class name are actually separator **between** class names. So the div is part of two classes, namely `listitem` **and** `show-in-category`

If you must select only elements that match both classes, you can do this:

```
Elements mydesiredElems = doc.select("div.listitem.show-in-category")
```

The dot followed by a class name is the css selector for a class. They can be concatenated and that results in adding this class as a requirement to match the element.

About your second question: Jsoup can easily get the img element for you. Suppose that myDivEl is one of your divs

```
Element imgEl = myDivEl.select("img");
String altStr = imgEl.attr("alt");
String titleStr = imgEl.attr("title");
```

UPDATE after question was edited to point out what the OP wants:

```
Element itemPropPEl = myDivEl.select("p[itemprop=description]");
String descStr = itemPropPEl.text();
```

Comment: THank you @luksch! I thought it was a single class name with spaces in between.  How can I get the itemprops (image, description, etc) in each Element in `mydesiredElems`?

Comment: i added that part just now

Comment: This did not work: `for (Element div: mydesiredElems) {div.attr("description");}`

Comment: the div has no attribute called ```description```, so this can't work. What do you expect to find?

Comment: `<p itemprop="description"><p>` was deleted in one of the edits, I put it back.