# Can't figure out how to scrape specific text - Using Jsoup

Tags: java, web, web-scraping, jsoup

I just started learning how to use JSoup. I think I've successfully selected this section of the html, and I successfully took "DARK SOULS III Deluxe Edition" out by doing .select("span.title").text but I was trying to get the prices, in this case $84.98 and $55.23. I tried doing .select("div.col search_price  responsive_secondrow").text but it comes up as blank. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to extract that part, thanks in advance! Here's the html of the section of the page.

The full html is view-source:http://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers

```
<a href="http://store.steampowered.com/sub/94174/?snr=1_7_7_topsellers_150_1"  data-ds-packageid="94174" data-ds-appid="374320,442010"onmouseover="GameHover( this, event, 'global_hover', {&quot;type&quot;:&quot;sub&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:94174,&quot;public&quot;:1,&quot;v6&quot;:1} );" onmouseout="HideGameHover( this, event, 'global_hover' )" class="search_result_row ds_collapse_flag" >
                <div class="col search_capsule"><img src="http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/subs/94174/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1476893662"></div>
                <div class="responsive_search_name_combined">
                    <div class="col search_name ellipsis">
                        <span class="title">DARK SOULS III Deluxe Edition</span>
                        <p>
                            <span class="platform_img win"></span>                          </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col search_released responsive_secondrow">12 Apr, 2016</div>
                    <div class="col search_reviewscore responsive_secondrow">
                                                        <span class="search_review_summary positive" data-store-tooltip="Very Positive&lt;br&gt;86% of the 29,204 user reviews for games in this bundle are positive.">
                            </span>
                                                </div>


                    <div class="col search_price_discount_combined responsive_secondrow">
                        <div class="col search_discount responsive_secondrow">
                            <span>-35%</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow">
                            <span style="color: #888888;"><strike>$84.98</strike></span><br>$55.23                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div style="clear: left;"></div>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use doc.select("a.search_result_row") instead:

```
public class JsoupSteamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers").userAgent("Mozilla")
                .get();

        Elements table = doc.select("a.search_result_row");

        Iterator<Element> ite = table.iterator();
        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            Element element = ite.next();
            System.out.println(element.text());

        }
    }
}
```

You will get a list like this:

```
PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS 23 Mar, 2017 29,99€
Steel Division: Normandy 44 Coming Soon 39,99€
DARK SOULS™ III 11 Apr, 2016 -50% 59,99€ 29,99€
```

**Your particular problem comes from the div that has multiple classes.**

To select an element that has multiple classes, use a dot instead of a space in your select:

```
doc.select("div.col.search_price.discounted.responsive_secondrow");
```

Take a look at this question: [JSOUP get element with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967413/jsoup-get-element-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: Thanks I thought the price was in a single class until I saw that post. I was wondering how a.search_result_row is able to filter the title, date and price? I saw a lot of other a tags in the html

Comment: Yes but "a.search_result_row" means "search_result_row under an element  a href". It acts like a filter